# Пример программы конвертации XLS файла в txt на C#

Tags: c#, xls

Нужен пример кода,который конвертирует файл из excel в обычный txt файл

Comment: Csv файл...или какой нить пакет для работы с екселем

Comment: Каким образом вы хотите таблицы, формулы и графики конвертировать в текст?

Comment: нет  только значения из таблицы

Answer (score 0):

Вот так это можно сделать с помощью OLE DB:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        //находит максимальную длину элемента для всех столбцов DataTable
        static int[] maxlen(DataTable dt) 
        {
            int[] res = new int[dt.Columns.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                res[i] = 0;
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    string s = row[i].ToString();
                    if (s.Length > res[i]) res[i] = s.Length;
                }
            }
            return res;
        }

        //выводит таблицу в текстовый файл
        static void print(DataTable dt, StreamWriter wr)
        {
            int[] len = maxlen(dt);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < row.ItemArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    string s = row[i].ToString().PadLeft(len[i]);
                    wr.Write(s + " | ");
                }
                wr.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xlspath = "c:\\test\\test.xls";
            string txtpath = "c:\\test\\test.txt";

            string strConn = string.Empty;
            string sheetName = string.Empty;

            var builder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;'");
            builder.DataSource = xlspath;
            strConn = builder.ConnectionString;

            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
            using (conn)
            {
                conn.Open();

                //получаем список листов
                DataTable dtSchema = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });

                FileStream fs = new FileStream(txtpath, FileMode.Create);
                using (fs)
                {
                    StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8);
                    using (wr)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow row in dtSchema.Rows)
                        {
                            //выводим имя файла
                            sheetName = row.Field<string>("TABLE_NAME");
                            wr.WriteLine("* Лист "+ sheetName);
                            wr.WriteLine();

                            //получаем содержимое листа
                            DataTable tbContainer = new DataTable();
                            OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(string.Format("select * from [{0}]", sheetName), conn);
                            oda.Fill(tbContainer);

                            //выводим таблицу
                            print(tbContainer, wr);
                            wr.WriteLine();
                        }                        
                    }
                }                
            }

            Console.Write("OK");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Данный пример не требует наличия Excel или какого-то другого ПО на целевой машине, но:

1. Работает только в Windows (2000+).
2. Работает только в 32-битных приложениях.
3. Имеет проблемы с чтением данных в случае, когда один столбец содержит в основном числовые значения + несколько текстовых значений (текстовые могут иногда не прочитаться).

Последняя проблема может быть решена установкой следующих значений в реестре на целевых машинах:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel]
ImportMixedTypes = Text
TypeGuessRows = 0
```

Comment: А почему только на 32-ух разрядных? Можно же узнать версию ОС и если х64, то сделать коннект через ACE. Правда, возможно, дрова нужно будет поставить.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Ну да, для этого нужно будет поставить либо офис, либо Access Database Engine, причем именно 64-разрядный.